# How to trim the branch name "refs/heads/feature/branch name" in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, the result of Pipeline variable $(Build.SourceBranch)="refs/heads/feature/branchname".
But I need to trim the value and get the output as just "feature/branchname" and delete "refs/heads"

1. Note 1 : replace() function will solve the issue, but I am looking for other feasible solutions.
2. Note 2 : Tried with TrimStart() in powershell. But,it is giving the result as "ture/branchname" instead of "feature/branchname"

Can someone please suggest the best way of handling this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `("refs/heads/feature/branchname" -split '/')[2..3] -join '/'`  ?

Comment: @Olaf -  yes, this works and tested in my local. But ,can you please help in understanding this?

Comment: You split the string at the forward slash, take the third and forth element of the resulting array and join them with a forward slash.

Comment: @Olaf  Thanks a lot. Got it. Also, Is there anyway to get the same output without hardcode indexing?

Comment: It depends pretty much on your input and your requirement. In your question you showed exactly one case.

Comment: Use relative indexing (-1 = very last item) e.g. `("x/y/z/refs/heads/feature/branchname" -split '/')[-2..-1] -join '/'`

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable time